# Convert TUnicodeStrings to TStrings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, unicode-string

In Delphi XE7 I use the well known DragAndDropSuite from Anders Melander. The `TDropFileTarget` component from this suite gives back the dropped files as `TUnicodeStrings`. However, I NEED to use these files in a procedure which has a `TStrings` parameter:

```
procedure DoSomethingWithTheseFiles(const AFiles: TStrings);
begin
  // Do something...
end;

procedure DropFileTarget1Drop(Sender: TObject;
    ShiftState: TShiftState; APoint: TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
begin
  DoSomethingWithTheseFiles(DropFileTarget1.Files); // TUnicodeStrings
end;
```

So with this code I get the error `E2010 Incompatible types: 'TStrings' and 'TUnicodeStrings'`

So how can I convert the `TUnicodeStrings` to `TStrings`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TUnicodeStrings` has support for the `Assign()` and `AssignTo()` methods of `TPersistent`. It knows how to copy strings to/from a `TStrings` object, eg:

```
Strings.Assign(UnicodeStrings);
```

Or:

```
UnicodeStrings.AssignTo(Strings);
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
var
  Strings: TStringList;
begin  
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.Assign(DropFileTarget1.Files);
    DoSomethingWithTheseFiles(Strings);
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks David - I very much appreciate your answers! Is this also safe to use when `DropFileTarget1.AllowAsyncTransfer` is set to True? Is it possible that in this case `DoSomethingWithTheseFiles` could already return and `Strings` be freed while `DropFileTarget1` is still working with these strings in a background thread?

Comment: `DropFileTarget1` doesn't know about `Strings`. It just has a copy of the strings. However, if `DropFileTarget1` is modifying the strings whilst you are assigning them to `Strings` then that's a problem. It's a problem with the code in the question too, not specifically to the code here which is just about `TUnicodeStrings` -> `TStrings`. I suppose you need to check up on the threading issue.

Comment: When `AllowAsyncTransfer` is true, the `OnDrop` event handler is not called until after the dragged data has been fully transferred, however be aware that it is called in the context of the background transfer thread (as the `Effect` value your handler returns has to be sent back to the drag source by the thread), so it must be thread-safe if you use `AllowAsyncTransfer=True`.